# How to fix the Error : TypeError : Cannot read properly 'setValues' of undefined google app script. How to implement it to my the code?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I made files with table. On those table there is some datas that are changing according to each files. So I created a file where there is a table that sum all of the others tables that are in others files.
First i made my code that sum tables of two files :

```
function juneFunction() {
  var sheet_origin1=SpreadsheetApp
                      .openById("ID1")
                      .getSheetByName("Calcul/Machine");
  var sheet_origin2=SpreadsheetApp
                      .openById("ID2")
                      .getSheetByName("Calcul/Machine"); 
  var sheet_destination=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  //define range as a string in A1 notation
  var range1="BU4:CF71"  
  var values1=sheet_origin1.getRange(range1).getValues();
  var values2=sheet_origin2.getRange(range1).getValues(); 
  var destinationrange=sheet_destination.getRange("C3:N70");
  //Here you sum the values of equivalent cells from different sheets
  for(var i=0; i<values1.length;i++)
  {
    for(var j=0; j<values1[0].length;j++)
    {
      sum=values1[i][j]+values2[i][j];
      destinationrange.getCell(i+1,j+1).setValue(sum);
    }
  } 
}
```

This code is working perfectly.
But my goal is to sum 26 tables of 26 files.
So I tried to do it with 3 files, here is the code :

```
function juneFunction() {

  var sheet_origin1=SpreadsheetApp
                      .openById("ID1")
                      .getSheetByName("Calcul/Machine");
  var sheet_origin2=SpreadsheetApp
                      .openById("ID2")
                      .getSheetByName("Calcul/Machine");
  var sheet_origin3=SpreadsheetApp
                      .openById("ID3")
                      .getSheetByName("Calcul/Machine");
  var sheet_destination=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  
  
  //define range as a string in A1 notation
  var range1="BU4:CF71"  
  
  var values1=sheet_origin1.getRange(range1).getValues();
  var values2=sheet_origin2.getRange(range1).getValues();
  var values3=sheet_origin3.getRange(range1).getValues();
  
  var destinationrange=sheet_destination.getRange("C3:N70");
  
  //Here you sum the values of equivalent cells from different sheets
  for(var i=0; i<values1.length;i++)
  {
    for(var j=0; j<values1[0].length;j++)
    {
      for(var k=0; k<values1[0].length;k++){
        sum=values1[i][j][k]+values2[i][j][k]+values3[i][j][k];
        destinationrange.getCell[[i+1,j+1,k+1]].setValues(sum);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here I have this error : TypeError : Cannot read properly 'setValues' of undefined. This error happen here :

```
destinationrange.getCell[[i+1,j+1,k+1]].setValues(sum);
```

I think that the error is coming from the .getCell but i dont know why ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Range.getCell()` takes two arguments: the row offset and the column offset. You are handing it just one argument: an array of three numbers.

You should not be using `Range.getCell()` in the first place. Instead, use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the sheets, [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over them, and finally `Range.setValues()` to write all results in one go, like this:

```
function sumRangeAcrossManySpreadsheets() {
  const spreadSheetIds = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3',];
  const sheetName = 'Calcul/Machine';
  const rangeA1 = 'BU4:CF71';
  const targetRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C3');
  const sheets = spreadSheetIds.map(id => SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(sheetName));
  const result = [];
  sheets.forEach((sheet, sheetIndex) => {
    if (!sheet) {
      throw new Error(`There is no sheet ${sheetName} in spreadsheet ID '${spreadSheetIds[sheetIndex]}'.`);
    }
    const values = sheet.getRange(rangeA1).getValues();
    values.forEach((row, rowIndex) => row.forEach((value, columnIndex) => {
      if (!result[rowIndex]) {
        result[rowIndex] = new Array(row.length).fill(0);
      }
      result[rowIndex][columnIndex] += Number(value) || 0;
    }));
  });
  targetRange.offset(0, 0, result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result);
}
```

Comment: thx for your answer and your explanation, but now I got the error : 
TypeError : values.forEach is not a function.

Comment: that fixed it but now the table display #NUMBER! in cells.
The datas can an int or a float.
For example that can be "4" or "4.5"

Comment: okay thats working perfectly ! 
I will try to understand all of the code now but thx for your help :)